# Android: ViewPager always show the second page at the start

Tags: android, android-fragments, position, android-viewpager, pager

I created a small Android applications, which use Viewpager for reading a story. Here is my code:

Override the getItem() method of FragmentStatePagerAdapter:

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    TextStoryChapter chapter = (TextStoryChapter) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("chapter");
        return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position,chapter);
    }
```

The create() method of `ScreenSlidePageFragment` class:

```
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
private int mPageNumber;
private static String chapterName;
private static String content;

public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber, TextStoryChapter chapter) {
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
    TextStoryChapterDetail detail = chapter.pages.get(pageNumber);
    chapterName = "Page " + Integer.toString(detail.pageNo);
    content = detail.content;
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

And the onCreate() method of `ScreenSlidePageFragment` class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    Log.e("PageNumber", Integer.toString(mPageNumber));
}
```

But when I run the applications, the ViewPager always display the content of page 2 (I created a `TextStoryChapter` with 5 content pages) at the start and the same content at the next page. The content of page 1 just disappear. When I navigated to page 3 and slided back to page 1, everything became normal again, no more duplicate content of page 2, and I don't know why and how it happen. Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a lock at your code. When ViewPager created, 2 variables `chapterName` and `chapterContent` data will be re-assign and your page 1 data will be lost. You should post your data into a `Bundle`, this will help.